# StackOverflowError coming when cxf security authentication webservice deployed in jboss 5.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

deployed webservice in jboss 5 with ws authentication  related stuff mentioned in

beans.xml file.

same service worked well in tomcat 6 and when i deploy same service getting

java.lang.StackOverflowError

in jboss 5.in server.log apart form this error i didn't find any error.

when i comment   from  to   then its working

fine.

I suspect  jars conflict with cxf jars and jboss jars.

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="ping" implementor="cxfdemo.ws10.impl.PingServiceImpl"
              address="/PingService">

  <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean id="xxx" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <property name="properties">
                <map>
                <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
                <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
     </jaxws:endpoint>
```

2013-01-22 03:20:08,667 INFO  QuartzScheduler_BpmClusteredScheduler-that missed their

scheduled fire-time.

2013-01-22 03:20:32,559 ERROR http-0.0.0.0-38080-3 [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase

.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/PingWS].[cxf]] Servlet.service() for servlet cxf threw exception

java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:78)

at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:62)


</code>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the conflict is with the jars that come with JBoss as part of its webservices library. I tried the following and it worked:

Remove jbossws.deployer from /deployers

Remove jbossws.sar from /deploy