# Turn off JBoss WS module in JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, cxf

I'am trying to deploy my CXF web application to JBoss 5.1 GA. All features work fine in Tomcat, but the internal JBoss-WS jars are causing some unexpected behavior (the same as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454420/stackoverflowerror-coming-when-cxf-security-authentication-webservice-deployed-i)), therefore I want to turn the Jboss webservice subsystem down as it is written [here.](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html).

The problem is that placing *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* in the WEB-INF does not have any effect even after restarting the server, so I assume it is not supported in version 5.1. Removing  *jbossws.deployer* from /deployers and *jbossws.sar* from /deploy (as written [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5xTuningSlimming)) is not a valid option because there are many applications which may be affected by it.

So my question is how to disable the internal JBoss WS module?

Many thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

See section "6.2.1 Configuration" of JAX-WS specification. Point 1 says:

> 1. If a resource with the name of `META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` exists, then its first line, if present, is used as the UTF-8 encoded name of the implementation class.

There's `JBOSS_HOME/common/lib/jbossws-native-jaxws.jar` JAR which contains `META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` file which contains:

```
org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

So according to point 2 or 3 of aforementioned specification, you can:

- use `${java.home}/lib/jaxws.properties`
- use system property with the name `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider`

I've done this with JBoss 6 when tried to use newest CXF provider.